# Visual Studio Code + TypeScript referencing renamed file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I had a file called `FooBar.ts` and decided to rename it to `fooBar.ts` but now VS Code keeps referencing the old file. I had to disable `forceConsistentCasingInFileNames` from `tsconfig.json` othewise it would keep thinking there were two files with only different casing, but even then, when trying to add the import automatically, VS Code still references the old file.

I tried cleaning it's cache but still getting the same error. Is it something I'm doing wrong or some sort of config I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

> I tried cleaning it's cache but still getting the same error. Is it something I'm doing wrong or some sort of config I'm missing?

Make sure the old file does not exist and then just restart vscode

## More

You might need to name file differently intermediately e.g. `Foo` -> `foos` -> `foo`.